# Django-Tinymce Import Error

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#testing) on getting tinymce working with django and zinnia. It's not working, so I am attempting to do "Testing" but get this error when I run `django-admin.py syncdb`. How do I fix this?

```
$django-admin.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('Django==1.5.1', 'django-admin.py')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 505, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1245, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'testtinymce.staticfiles_settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named staticfiles_settings
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you run this before syncdb ? `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='testtinymce.staticfiles_settings'` ?

Comment: I did. I've tried it in a virtual env and on the system and I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Alternatively you can also put this ina settings file and try

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Seems to have started working. Future readers might try a restart to see if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the django-tinymce documentation is outdated, i.e. partially wrong.

What I discovered is that different versions of tinymce and django-tinymce packages are not compatible.

I solved it adding some variables to my project/settings.py and altering the tinymce directory and file names.

django-tinymce urls.py had some hardcoded paths in it which assumed the directories were named "tiny_mce" when in reality they were named "tinymce", hence I had to rename them, or alternatively you can change the hardcoded paths in django-tinymce's urls.py.

```
# project setting.py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_JS_DIR = os.path.join(STATIC_DIR, "js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_JS_DIR, "tiny_mce")
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(TINYMCE_JS_ROOT, "tiny_mce.js")
#TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_JS_DIR, "tiny_mce")
#TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(TINYMCE_JS_ROOT, "tiny_mce.js")
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple shutdown of the terminal, then restarting the app again fixed it for me (without needing to configure anything extra).  I followed the instructions [here](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html):

1. pip install django-tinymce
2. Add `tinymce` to the INSTALLED_APPS of 'settings.py'
3. Add `(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),` to the urlpatterns in urls.py
4. Do a `python manage.py syncdb`  (not sure if this is needed)
5. In terminal: `$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='testtinymce.staticfiles_settings'`
6. Do another `python manage.py syncdb` just in case and then a `python manage.py runserver`
7. I then received the error when I tried to open up the browser to: `http://localhost:8000/admin/myapphere`
8. I restarted the terminal, did a 'collect static' just in case, then did `python manage.py runserver` and it worked (I was able to see the new fields)

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of tinymce has a different configuration.
instead of Importing HTMLField like 
    from tinymce import HTMLField 
but rather
    from tinymce.models import HTMLField